Motion starts but won't stay up as a service
I have a DSLR which I plug in USB to get a video stream using gphoto2 piped with ffmpeg. This works and my stream gets in /dev/video0.
All that on a Pi 4
I want to use motion to stream that to port 8081, hence I modified the motion.conf accordingly. The problem is that the daemon dies, while the process stays up if I simply launch it manually!
Here's what I get with the daemon
myuser@myserver:/var/lib $ sudo service motion start
myuser@myserver:/var/lib $ sudo service motion status
● motion.service - Motion detection video capture daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/motion.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2024-06-06 23:12:18 CEST; 4s ago
Docs: man:motion(1)
Process: 15448 ExecStart=/usr/bin/motion (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 15448 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CPU: 334ms

juin 06 23:12:16 myserver systemd[1]: Started Motion detection video capture daemon.
juin 06 23:12:17 myserver motion[15448]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
juin 06 23:12:17 myserver motion[15448]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
juin 06 23:12:17 myserver motion[15448]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)
juin 06 23:12:17 myserver motion[15448]: [0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)
juin 06 23:12:18 myserver systemd[1]: motion.service: Succeeded.

There, nothing works, the stream is not on port 8081 and even the control interface isn't working (of course: the process exited).
Why does this service stops???
And there's not a single clue in the log: everything seems perfectly normal... except it gracefully stops (mlp_action: end of event 1, motion_loop: exiting thread, cleaning v4l2, closing /dev/video0, ending threads, ending Motion, and closing log file), just like it was going "yeah, I'm successfully loaded, goodbye".
Weirdly enough, if I simply sudo motion, everything works fine...

Check if the user running the service has the necessary permissions to access /dev/video0 and other required resources.

I use motion on a RPi3. Check the permissions. Also, check your service configuration. For example, will the service be restarted if it is found not running. How often will it restart. Who is the service running as. And more IIRC. Also, once you do get things going, make sure you have plans for any videos that you are storing. I maxed out the SDCard and it took a while to get things running smoothly again.

Well, I may be mistaken, but when doing sudo service motion start, the user running the service is supposed to be root, which have permissions on all /dev/video* (as owner)...
Anyways, I'll try setting myuser and www-data into the video group.
